# Error during export .pst file in outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook, export, import, pst

On my old PC I use Outlook 2007. On my new PC I use Outlook 2010. I want to move all my email folders and emails to my new computer. I think the only way to do this is by export my files to a .PST file in Outlook 2007 and then import the .PST file with Outlook 2010.

But when trying to make a PST file in outlook 2007 this error occurs: "Internal translation system error"

What can I do? Are there any other ways to move my folders and emails to my new PC with Outlook 2010?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure Outlook is closed and locate the .pst file.

Copy the file to your new PC.

Create a new account in Outlook 2010 but ensure you choose the location of the file - browse for the .pst and select it.

This will keep what you had and all new emails will populate this file - Outlook will read the file and structure folders accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever try [Export Outlook Items to PST Format](http://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookStorageExportFolders/) tool? It's **free** and easy to use. I'm one of its developers, so feel free to ask any further questions.